# What are the orbs on zen cactus?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-garden-warfare-2

I recently unlocked Zen Cactus. The description says "Each time Zen Cactus fires a shot, her Mystic Orbs grow in size and power!" However it does not specify what the orbs do. Now I need to know if it's worth maining him over various other unlocked cactus'. So I was wondering just that: what *do* the glowing orbs do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mystic Orbs are Zen Cactus main weapon. For each fired shot, the next shot will be more powerful until it runs out of ammo.

It deals 20 damage with direct hits for the first shot. Every orb fired increases the damage dealt by 10 points until it caps at 60 points of damage for the fifth and final orb.

[Source](https://plantsvszombies.fandom.com/wiki/Zen_Cactus)

Comment: That's pretty cool! I think I may start using him now, thank you!